# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on login screen

Tags: 16.04, suspend, login-screen, freeze

The OS freezes sometimes (sometimes frequently) when I open the laptop lid.
Ubuntu was started before, successfully logged in and some work had been done. Everything went alright until I closed the lid and (after some time) opened it again. In a normal situation I could just log in with my password, but sometimes I can't.
The screen isn't completely frozen. Mouse is moving, the password field is filling and the panel icons seem to react on cursor covering (without showing the menus). But nothing happens. No movement inside the laptop, no sound. It looks like it is switched off. No possibility to switch to the TTY. Only reset with the power button works. All unsaved data is lost.
What do I do guys? I have completely no idea.
My laptop is `Lenovo V580c` with hybrid graphics Nvidia (updating driver didn't help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing laptop-mode-tools.
Battery consumption had increased by about 20%, but this was solved by installing `tlp`.

Answer (score 0):

sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave

sudo update-grub

## reboot

sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave

sudo apt-get install thermald

## tlp advanced power mgmt

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start

sudo apt-get install smartmontools ethtool